# Meteor template not updating in JQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor

I'm trying to get a div to fade out and then change a session variable which is being used in the template. The session variable is being successfully changed in the callback function but the template is not reactively updating.

The following **does not** reactively update the template. (These are trigger)

```
$(event.target.parentNode).find(subclass)
                          .fadeOut("slow", function() {
    Session.set(this.valueOf() + "_show_exercise_fields", set_show_exercise_fields);
```

The following **does** reactively update the template.

```
Session.set(this.valueOf() + "_show_exercise_fields", set_show_exercise_fields);
$(event.target.parentNode).find(subclass)
                          .fadeOut("slow", function() {
    // do nothing
});
```

Is there a way to force the template to re render or a better way to do what I am trying to do. Thanks

---

## EDIT 1

Below is the entire function

```
Template.exercise.events({
'click .exercise-name': function(event) {
    var subclass                 = ".exercise-fields-container";
    var set_show_exercise_fields = false;

    if (!Session.get(this.valueOf() + "_show_exercise_fields")) {
        var subclass                 = ".exercise-options-container";
        var set_show_exercise_fields = true;
    }

    // find the subclass (either the fields container or the options
    // container) and fade out
    $(event.target.parentNode).find(subclass)
                              .fadeOut("slow", function() {
        Session.set(this.valueOf() + "_show_exercise_fields", set_show_exercise_fields);
    });
}
});

Template.exercise.helpers({
    show_fields: function() {
        Session.setDefault(this.valueOf() + "_show_exercise_fields", true);
        return Session.get(this.valueOf() + "_show_exercise_fields");
    }
});
```

Below is the template

```
<template name="exercise">
    <div class="exercise-name">
        {{this.name}}
    </div>

    {{#if show_fields}}
        Fields
    {{else}}
        Options
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: I don't understand why your second snippet reactively updates. It is not clear what the reactive data source is that triggers that. Can you expand/explain? or is what you are showing the trigger (not the reaction)?

Comment: The reactive data source is the session variable `this.valueOf() + "_show_exercise_fields"`. What I was showing is the trigger, sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: This is a really weird pattern. What are you trying to have your template react to? Clearly you're explicitly handling the click event. Are you trying to react to changes elsewhere to the Session variable? If so why don't you just have your click event simply update the Session variable and have a `tracker.autorun()` do the fadeout based on the Session variable?

Comment: also, your `setDefault` should not be in the helper. The way I understand reactivity is that the whole encapsulating function will be rerun, i.e., your setDefault should run every time. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: @ChristianFritz setDefault does not run if it has been set in the past. This does not impact reactivity and have seen this practice in use before. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_set_default

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'm trying to have my template react to the click event. Could you give an example on how I could use `tracker.autorun()` in this situation. I don't want to change the template reactively **until** I finish fading out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers aren't reactive contexts. You can create a reactive context using Tracker.autorun().

If you use a session variable within the function you pass to autorun, the entire function will rerun whenever the session variable is changed. In this context you could fade in or out as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario where a collection was being updated, so I had to re-build my select element using [Materialize Select](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select)

Here's what my on rendered function looks like. The autorun knows that Channels is a reactive data source and re-runs the autorun function when this data source changes.

```
Channels = new Mongo.Collection("channels");

Template.channelSelectController.onRendered(function(){
    var self = this;

    this.autorun(function(){
        var count = Channels.find().count();
        self.$('select').material_select();
    });
});
```